# Algebra operation with real numbers

Tags: inequality

This is in my GMAT prep book ... is it wrong?

Given:  [y] denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to y. Is d<1?

(1)  d= y-[y]. Is this sufficient to answer the question?  YES (I agree with this)
(2)  [d] = 0.  Their answer = it follows that d<1 so YES, it is sufficient to answer the question.

My beef with #2 is that their solution requires that [d] is defined like [y].  But it isn't defined like this anywhere.  Therefore, I don't believe we can logically make this assumption.  Am I wrong?

(FYI - GMAT gives us two minutes to answer this question)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're wrong. The Given clearly states "$[y]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $y$", which *logically* implies that $[d]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to d. Since $d<1, [d]=0$.